# Integrating Paypal chained payment and direct payment?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to Use the Paypal API for chained payment (adaptive payment), but i wan't that the user will not get out from my site, so I need to use the DoDirectPayment also...

Is it possible to integrate them both?
I couldn't found the answer for this question...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They both are part of two different API suites from PayPal. The chained payment is from Adaptive Payments API and DoDirectPayment is from PayPal Payments Pro (Direct edition). So make sure you sign up for them as required.

As Prash mentioned, for chained payments w/ PayPal accounts you must redirect to PayPal. But instead of using full browser redirect - you can use the Embedded Payments experience that uses iframe/mini-browser window that provides a more contextual experience to your users.

Comment: So basically you are saying that i cant use the direct payment with the chained payment? i must to redirect to paypal (full browser or iframe)?

Comment: that's correct. Your consumers can pay by logging in with their PayPal account or just pay as a guest with their credit card on the PayPal login page.

Answer (score 0):

The user must leave your site in order to login to PayPal, however they are redirected back to your site afterwards where you can process the payment.